# How to indicate the activity that a professor is required to do under the rules of the University?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm translating a sentence from Russian:

> In summary, if full-time professors or researchers are engaged by Company for consultations, such activities may be either free of any restrictions or require prior university authorization, based on the **prescribed activity**.

Would this "prescribed activity" mean "the activity that such professors/researchers are prescribed to perform under the rules of their respective universities"? Or would it be confusing for the reader?

I'm looking for a word or a short phrase that may replace **prescribed**. Maybe "titular"?

P.S. The original Russian sentence:

> Подводя итог, можно сказать, что в случае привлечения Компанией для консультаций штатных профессоров или научных сотрудников, такая деятельность может быть свободной от каких-либо ограничений или требовать предварительного разрешения на основании **предписанного вида деятельности**.

Comment: I might say "based on the nature of the work and the university's rules" if the purpose of the sentence is to explain that some activities may be subject to restrictions that others may not depending upon what the university's rules are for that type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, and not specific to academia, the tasks that you are required to do for your job is called your "job description", which forms part of the "contract"

> Your job description clearly states that you are expected to be at your desk by 8 am each day. You were late five times last month and therefore we are terminating your employment.

The English is rather confusing, but I'm not going to do a full rewrite.  I think you mean "... based on their job description", or perhaps "contractual activities",  though the use of "may" seems to suggest that there is actually no requirement at all, since "may" also allows for "might not".

The usual way that legal documents work is, in the header there is a glossary

> **Prescribed activity** The activities that a Professor is required to do under the rules of the university.

Then there is no problem using your term in the body of the document.  This would be my prefered solution, especially if you need to use this term more than once.